# I have a coding problem and the bot does not do the requested function

Tags: javascript

Being new to the IT field, I want to create an entertainment and moderation bot but I encounter several problems:

> Process exited with code 1
> Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: client is not defined

Here are my lines of code:

```
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Client({ intents: ["Guilds"] });
console.log("Connexion au bot...");
bot.login("MY TOKEN")
    .then(() => console.log("Connecté au bot !"))
    .catch((error) => console.log("Impossible de se connecter au bot - " + error));

bot.on("ready", async () => {

    await bot.application.commands.set([
        {
            name: "ping",
            description: "Pong!"
        }
    ]);

    console.log("Le bot est prêt !");
});

bot.on("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {

    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === "ping")
        interaction.reply("Pong!");

    if (interaction.commandName === "maj")
        interaction.reply("Pour connaître les derniers mises à jours du bot, merci de 
vous référencer à Xinfeng");
});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
if(message.author.bot) return;

    //+help
 if (message.content === prefix + "help"){
    const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor("#ffcc00")
        .setTitle("**__Les commandes du bot__**")
        .setURL("https://discord.js.org/")
        .setDescription("Vous trouverez toutes les commandes dont vous pouvez faire 
usage")
        .addFields(
            { name: '**__+commandes:__**', value: 'Affiche la liste des commandes' },
            { name: '**__+description:__**', value: 'Affiche la description du bot' },
            { name: '**__+info:__**', value: 'Affiche les informations du bot' },
            { name: '**__Support Developpement:__**', value: 
'https://discord.gg/H9mSXeAm8C' }
       
        );
        
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]});

}
  //+description
  if (message.content === prefix + "description"){
    const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor("#ffcc00")
        .setTitle("**__Description du bot__**")
        .setURL("https://discord.js.org/")
        .setDescription("Je suis Athéna, une déesse grec de l'artisanat et de la 
stratégie guerrière. Je m'occupe de la modération, jeux et de trackage d’information ");

    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]});

}


    console.log(message);
    if(message.content === "Salut"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "salut"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Coucou"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "coucou"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Hey"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Heyyy"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Hello"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Hello tlm"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "hello"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "hello tlm"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Hoyaa"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Hey tlm"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "slt tlm"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Slt tlm"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "hey"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    if(message.content === "Bonjour"){
        message.reply("Bonjour jeune aventurier");
    }
    else if(message.content === "help"){
        message.channel.send("**__les commandes du bot ATHENA sont__**\n - +help: Il 
permettra de configurer et de mieux comprendre les commandes")
    }
    else if(message.content === "description"){
        message.channel.send("**__Pour connaître la description du bot ATHENA 
sont__**\n - +description: Il permettra de connaître l'histoire et la naîssance du 
bot")
    }
    else if(message.content === "mention"){
        message.reply("Mention d'un utilisateur : <@" + message.author.id + "> \n 
Mention d'un salon : <#" + message.channel.id + ">");
    }

});
```

I would like to know if we can resolve this problem and also if I did the lines of code correctly, thank you.

Comment: The bot instance is assigned to the variable `bot` and not `client`

Comment: Error message is clear - there is no `client` defined (**JS is case sensitive!**). That's why `client.on("messageCreate"` fails